# How do I get the previously selected cell in a DataGridView cell click event

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a DataGridView and I am allowing only one column to be able to be selected.
I did this by checking, in the `CellClick` event, if the `ColumnHeader` for the selected cell matches, and, if it doesn't, I will clear the selection.
However, I want to make it that it will return to the previously selected cell if they selected a cell in the wrong Column. How can I do that?

I tried storing the selected cell object but thats not going to work because the moment the `CellClick` event fires, the selected cell object will change.

Also, for some reason my clear selection doesn't work everytime I click the wrong cell, especially if I click it really fast the wrong cell will still stay selected, for your info the DataGridView `CellClick` event is added dynamically during runtime and there are multiple DataGridView controls.

My code I can't provide the way I use to populate the DataGridView because it is really long.

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DGV.CellClick += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(DGV_CellClick);
  }

  void DGV_CellClick(Object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
      DataGridView dgv = (DataGridView)sender;
      // DataGridViewCell Selectedcell = dgv.SelectedCells[0];
      if (!dgv.Columns[dgv.SelectedCells[0].ColumnIndex].HeaderText.Contains("SCORE"))
          dgv.ClearSelection();
  }
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am pretty sure that in the `CellClick` event, the previous cell info is lost. Have you tried to “globally” store the cells location on its “Leave” event? I am guessing a global “row/col” index could be changed when the user “leaves” a cell. Then if the user clicks into the wrong column/row, you could get the row index of the last selected cell from the global row/col variables. Just a thought.

Comment: @JohnG Hm i guess i can do that but i didnt know it requires so many steps, ill give it a try thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have just one Column enabled, using the [SelectionChanged](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.selectionchanged) event, you can determine whether the [DataGridView.CurrentCell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.currentcell) belongs to the enabled Column and if it's not set the `CurrentCell` to the Cell of the enabled Column in the current Row:

```
int dgvEnabledColumn = 1;

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    var currentCell = dgv.CurrentCell;
    if (currentCell.ColumnIndex != dgvEnabledColumn )
    {
        dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[dgvEnabledColumn, currentCell.RowIndex];
    }
}
```

---

You could expand the enabled Columns' selection using a collection of Columns (to set the current cell to the nearest/previous/next Column).

For example, using a collection of `DataGridViewColumn` objects, determine if the Current cell is enabled and, if it's not, set the Current cell to the nearest next enabled Column, if any, or the nearest previous one:

The **`List<DataGridViewColumn>`** can be filled after the DataGridView is initialized:

```
enabledColumns = new List<DataGridViewColumn>()
{
    dataGridView1.Columns[0],
    dataGridView1.Columns[2]
};
```

---

```
List<DataGridViewColumn> enabledColumns = null;

private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (enabledColumns is null) return;
    var dgv = sender as DataGridView;
    var currentCell = dgv.CurrentCell;
    if (!enabledColumns.Any(c => c.Index == currentCell.ColumnIndex))
    {
        var nextCol = enabledColumns.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Index > currentCell.ColumnIndex);
        if (nextCol != null) {
            dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[nextCol.Index, currentCell.RowIndex];
        }
        else
        {
            var previousCol = enabledColumns.First(c => c.Index < currentCell.ColumnIndex);
            dgv.CurrentCell = dgv[previousCol.Index, currentCell.RowIndex];
        }
    }
}
```